# System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Secure binary serialization is not supported on this platform

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

Please I need help for the below error I am getting. Whenever I query with the value that exists in the servicecontainer, it works fine. When the value does not exists, the below error surfaces:

code line that gives error:

```
BusinessPartner bp = currentServiceContainer.BusinessPartners.Where(
                    c=> c.cn==cn).SingleOrDefault();
```

I am using .Net core 2.2

```
Thanks

System.PlatformNotSupportedException
  HResult=0x80131539
  Message=Secure binary serialization is not supported on this platform.
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Exception.add_SerializeObjectState(EventHandler`1 value)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.HttpWebRequestMessage.ConvertToDataServiceWebException(WebException webException)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponse()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.GetResponseHelper(ODataRequestMessageWrapper request, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean handleWebException)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryProvider.ReturnSingleton[TElement](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at SAPB1Servicelayer.ServiceLayerService.GetBP(String cardCode) in C:\Programs\.Net\SAPB1Servicelayer\ServiceLayerService.cs:line 1320
   at SAPB1ServicelayerAPI.Services.SAPB1ServiceLayerServices.GetBusinessPartner(String cardCode) in C:\Programs\.Net\SAPB1ServicelayerAPI\SAPB1ServicelayerAPI\Services\SAPB1ServiceLayerServices.cs:line 46
   at SAPB1ServicelayerAPI.Controllers.BusinessPartnersController.Get(String cardCode) in C:\Programs\.Net\SAPB1ServicelayerAPI\SAPB1ServicelayerAPI\Controllers\BusinessPartnersController.cs:line 33
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
```